# ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')- km.fit(x)

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, prediction, pychart

I am using python for clustering a set of data that I have, but it is showing me this error and I do not where should I make the changes and in which file:

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

and the following is my code:

```
from sklearn import datasets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from apyori import apriori

dataset = pd.read_csv('autos1.csv',encoding= 'unicode_escape')

x = dataset.iloc[ : ,  1:3]

km = KMeans(n_clusters = 2, random_state = 21)

km.fit(x)

centers = km.cluster_centers_

print(centers)

clusters = x.copy()
clusters ['cluster_id'] = km.fit_predict(x)

plt.xlabel('price')
plt.ylabel('yearOfRegistration')

plt.scatter(clusters['fuelType'], clusters['yearOfRegistration'], c='black', cmap='rainbow')

plt.xlabel('price')
plt.ylabel('yearOfRegistration')

plt.show()

plt.scatter(centers[:,0], centers[:,1], c = 'black', s = 100 , alpha = 0.9 )
plt.scatter(clusters['price'], clusters['yearOfRegistration'], c=clusters['cluster_id'], cmap='rainbow')

plt.xlabel('price')
plt.ylabel('yearOfRegistration')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove any rows from your dataset that contain nan or nonfinite values.

```
# Only select rows that have all finite entries.
x = x[np.all(np.isfinite(x), axis=1)]
```

`np.isfinite` will return an array of the same shape as your input, so pass `axis=1` to `np.all` to check if all columns (axis 1) of each row are finite.
Then, index into your array to only select those rows.